# MS Outlook 2010 - Evaluate Response Time

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, tracking

Is there a way to track my response time to emails and task in Outlook 2010?  In other words, I am interested to know how long it takes to respond to emails.  Is there a way that this can be tracked in Outlook?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you researched or attempted so far?

Comment: How do you want to get these stats: per email or totals/averages?